# My Schizophrenic router and local network names

Tags: networking, router, ssh, dns, home-networking

My home network has a single router assigning IP addresses via DHCP. It reports local addresses as devicename@fritz.box. Except when it doesn't. The router itself always reports in that naming convention, but it doesn't always hold for devices on the network. There are times I can SSH from my macbook into one of the raspberry pis on my network with ssh@devicename.fritz.box and others that doesn't work but ssh@devicename.local does, and vice versa.

I cannot for the life of me detect a pattern. I have an Apple Airport which broadcasts WiFi - but it's set up in bridge mode and theoretically gets all Ips assigned by the Fritz.box DHCP. At any rate, the confusion over which local network name is going to work seems to persist whether I'm connected to the Apple Wifi SSID, the Fritz.box SSID (they're different) or plugged in via Internet. DNS for the Airport is assigned to the router's IP address. I realize this is an amorphous ask about a problem I can't consistently replicate - consider this a desperate fishing expedition. The problem of where to SSH is a minor annoyance, but I suspect this points to larger issues in the way my network is set up. For example, should I expect a broken pipe in my SSH connections whenever I move from LAN to wireless or from one wireless zone to another?

How do I even start to hunt down the source of a problem like this?

Comment: Device firmwares are up to date??

Comment: Yep: FritzBox 7581 running Fritz IOS 7.01